# Import PEF raw file from Pentax K-R into ps cs5 extended - not supported?

Tags: photoshop, raw, pentax

Im trying to import PEF raw files from a Pentax Kr, into photoshop cs5 extended (osx lion) but i keep getting an error message, is their a work arround or plugin i can use to over come this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the Pentax Kr is not supported by Adobe Camera Raw 5.x

see:

http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html

You need ACR version 6.3 or greater, I suggest you download the latest version (6.7) from here:

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5370